# Delegate and DataSource not woking in MessageKit Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, messagekit

I'm using the MessageKit for chating when I calling the its delegate and datasource it saying (Cannot find 'messagesCollectionView' in scope) please see the code and guide me thanks.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import MessageKit

struct Message: MessageType{
    var sender: SenderType
    var messageId: String
    var sentDate: Date
    var kind: MessageKind
}

struct sender: SenderType{
    var photo: String
    var senderId: String
    var displayName: String
}
class ChatDashboard: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblUser: UILabel!
    
    var userActive: String? = nil
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         messagesCollectionView.messagesDataSource = self
         messagesCollectionView.messagesLayoutDelegate = self
         messagesCollectionView.messagesDisplayDelegate = self //not working delegate and datasource
        if let userData = userActive{
            self.lblUser.text = userData
        }
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    }

}
```

Comment: It is right. You don't have a property called `messagesCollectionView` in your view controller

Comment: yes you're right

Comment: Can you please tell me ? How I can get this property properly I've seen tutorials that directly accessing the property without any warning

Comment: Well, in their [quick start guide](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/blob/master/Documentation/QuickStart.md) they subclass `MessagesViewController`, not `UIViewController` so that is probably a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at their example project usage.
Should clear out lots of confusion.

Link: https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/tree/master/Example

As for your query,

Can't find `messagesCollectionView` because `MessagesViewController`needs to be extended to access that.